# Job with create table

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

I create a `job` with the following query

```
CREATE TABLE P  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
                 [employee_name] varchar(10),
                 [employee_salary] varchar(10))
INSERT INTO P ([employee_name] ,[employee_salary] ) 
VALUES ('DANI','1000')
```

and i execute the job the following way

```
use[msdb]
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job xxx
GO 
use[DEMO]
select * from P
```

my question is-why i did not receive a massage "table already exists" while i execute it second time?

Comment: Maybe your job has failed becouse, the table alredy exists!

Comment: No,the table was not exist

Comment: Why have a create table inside a sql job? Why not just create the table and then have your job do what it needs to. Unless you are going to also drop the table this seems like a recipe for headaches to me.

Comment: You are right-no need to create table inside job. i just try to answer another question on SO and then faced this problem...To satisfy my curiosity , I posted the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbo.sp_start_job` just starts off the job and returns immediately. It doesn't synchronously wait for the result of whatever processing the job is doing.

You would probably see the expected error message if you check the job history.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your script to check if object exist before try to create it. The do the Insert